# Stored Procedure To set a variable value to a Individual column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a `Table structure` as

```
Empid Int,
EmpName Nvarchar,
Salary Numeric(18,2),
DeptNumber
```

I have Function which take 2 Argument. as :

```
ALTER Function [dbo].[GetTotalPrice] 
(
@Salary int,
@DeptNumber int
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
Declare @TotalSalary int
Select @TotalSalary=@Salary+@DeptNumber 
return @TotalSalary
End
```

And my Query is how should i develop a Stored procedure Which takes 
Each `salary` and `DeptNumber` in a Stored Procedure and send that to function and calculate a new Salary. i have tried developing several SP, but could not get any possible solution.

```
ALTER Proc [dbo].[S7] 
AS
BEGIN
Declare @salary int
Declare @DeptNo int
Select EmpId,EmpName, @salary=salary,@DeptNo=DeptNumber,Salary=dbo.GetTotalPrice(@salary,@DeptNo) 
from dbo.EmpInf
end
```

When i tried executing the above code it give the following error:

```
A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same `SELECT` to put data in the variables and returning a result set from the Stored Procedure, you can't do both in the same statement.

```
ALTER Proc [dbo].[S7] 
AS
BEGIN
Select EmpId,EmpName, Salary=dbo.GetTotalPrice(salary,DeptNumber) from dbo.EmpInf
end
```

Comment: Sir in this case of running 2 t-Sql,the Salary Column contain the sum of the last column of Salary and deptnumber of a table

Comment: Yes, I had just separated variable assignation and result SELECTs, I edited my answer and removed the variables, if you need to use these variable in another command you will need a cursor to iterate in every row.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 Select EmpId,EmpName,  
 salary=@salary,DeptNumber=@DeptNo,Salary=dbo.GetTotalPrice(@salary,@DeptNo)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear, you can combine the two

```
Declare @salary int
Declare @DeptNo int,
   @EmpId int, @EmpName varchar(50),
   @Salary int


Select @EmpId=EmpId, @EmpName=EmpName, @salary=salary,@DeptNo=DeptNumber,@Salary=dbo.GetTotalPrice(1000,'XXX') 
from dbo.EmpInf

Select @EmpId As EmpID, @EmpName As EmpName, @Salary As Salary
```

Or

```
Select EmpID, EmpName, Salary, dbo.GetTotalPrice(1000,'XXX') from dbo.EmpInf
```

You can combine the two, having the @XXX and XXX in the same Select query.

You either do `Select @X = value FROM table` OR `Select value From Table`, not both

Comment: Sir, using the concept above. My Sp return only the computed last row of the table.